# Apply a change curve to a dataframe

Tags: r

I have a table of weather data, and the idea is to run a model based on

a) the weather data
b) weather +1sd
c) weather -1sd

to come up with some type of confidence interval. So here I've got daily temps for two cities, and then the equivalent table of standard devs, broken out by month. What I want to do, is write a function that will transform the dataframe by applying the relevant, monthly, st.devs to each value. I.e with respect to the below, I want to add 9.07 degrees and 9.37 degrees to every November value for Boise and Idaho Falls, respectively... and then to add 9.15 and 11.03 degrees to all December values, again for Boise and Idaho falls respectively.

I know I could do this in a "messy" fashion with some intermediary steps, creating some columns and then ultimately cleaning them up. In the interest of learning, though, I'd like to understand how to execute a more elegant solution.

```
df <- structure(list(Date = c("2014-11-01", "2014-11-02", "2014-11-03", 
"2014-11-04", "2014-11-05", "2014-11-06", "2014-11-07", "2014-11-08", 
"2014-11-09", "2014-11-10", "2014-11-11", "2014-11-12", "2014-11-13", 
"2014-11-14", "2014-11-15", "2014-11-16", "2014-11-17", "2014-11-18", 
"2014-11-19", "2014-11-20", "2014-11-21", "2014-11-22", "2014-11-23", 
"2014-11-24", "2014-11-25", "2014-11-26", "2014-11-27", "2014-11-28", 
"2014-11-29", "2014-11-30", "2014-12-01", "2014-12-02", "2014-12-03", 
"2014-12-04", "2014-12-05", "2014-12-06", "2014-12-07", "2014-12-08", 
"2014-12-09", "2014-12-10", "2014-12-11", "2014-12-12", "2014-12-13", 
"2014-12-14", "2014-12-15", "2014-12-16", "2014-12-17", "2014-12-18", 
"2014-12-19", "2014-12-20", "2014-12-21", "2014-12-22", "2014-12-23", 
"2014-12-24", "2014-12-25", "2014-12-26", "2014-12-27", "2014-12-28", 
"2014-12-29", "2014-12-30"), BOISE = c(44.5, 42.5, 43.5, 47.5, 
55, 57.5, 49.5, 47.5, 45, 38, 31, 23.5, 24, 21.5, 11.5, 13, 13, 
13, 16, 22, 32, 42, 37, 38, 46.5, 48.5, 49.5, 52.5, 42, 26, 31.5, 
33, 40, 48.5, 40, 44, 43.5, 42, 42.5, 46, 57, 51, 39.5, 34, 36.5, 
39, 36.5, 40.5, 40.5, 40, 43.5, 39.5, 35.5, 33, 32, 29, 27, 31, 
27, 20.5699996948242), `IDAHO FALLS` = c(54.5, 36, 34.5, 35.5, 
41, 41.5, 47, 39, 45.5, 36, 15, 13, 14, 26, 4.5, 2.5, 8, 11, 
28, 27, 27, 35.5, 31.5, 33, 39, 43, 45.5, 46, 42.5, 28.5, 27, 
34, 35.5, 42, 36.5, 42.5, 35, 36, 34.5, 36.5, 42.5, 47, 39, 28, 
23.5, 31, 22.5, 24.5, 34.5, 35, 38.5, 34, 27.5, 31.5, 24.5, 8.5, 
15, 19, 10.5, -3.46000003814697)), class = "data.frame", .Names = c("Date", 
"BOISE", "IDAHO FALLS"), row.names = c(NA, -60L))

sd_matrix <- structure(list(month = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12
), BOISE = c(7.90623167260698, 6.46123050256436, 6.38106936624632, 
7.22283114115187, 7.76515042234502, 8.10445388054925, 5.65058663778116, 
6.18033208264487, 7.34160028246709, 7.48784870009556, 9.07481352622016, 
9.15757443706943), `IDAHO FALLS` = c(10.4267588417941, 9.89036971863809, 
7.99156512696757, 6.84627542213131, 6.6696338642145, 6.823026513784, 
4.31982292105468, 4.63179196395735, 6.38702016727256, 7.31441201561822, 
9.37466284053354, 11.0316440728702)), class = "data.frame", row.names =     c(NA, 
-12L), .Names = c("month", "BOISE", "IDAHO FALLS"))
```

Here is some hacky code that provides the right result in this particular instance but does not provide for things like variable names and size, which I will have to deal with --

```
df$month <- month(df$Date)
df <- inner_join(df, sd_matrix, by="month")

df$BOISE.x <- df$BOISE.x + df$BOISE.y
df$`IDAHO FALLS.x` <- df$`IDAHO FALLS.x` + df$`IDAHO FALLS.y`

df <- df %>%
  select(Date, BOISE.x, `IDAHO FALLS.x`) 
names(df) <- c("Date,", "Boise", "Idaho Falls")
```

Comment: `I could do this in a "messy" fashion...` please do try and share your code.

Comment: I edited the original to include this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should really read the [Tidy Data paper](http://vita.had.co.nz/papers/tidy-data.pdf) - it gives a very useful framework for thinking about things like this. That framework would say that your data is not tidy because your are encoding information in column names; namely, "location" is an important piece of data, but instead of putting location in a single column, you have it in multiple column names, and this makes everything more difficult than it needs to be.

We use `tidyr::gather` to convert your data into long format, with a single location column and a single temperature column:

```
library(tidyr)
l_df = gather(df, key = loc, value = temp, -Date)
l_sd = gather(sd_matrix, key = loc, value = sd, -month)
```

With that done, we can do a simple join on both location and month, and then add and subtract the standard deviations as needed:

```
result = mutate(l_df, month = lubridate::month(Date)) %>%
    inner_join(l_sd) %>%
    mutate(temp_u1 = temp + sd,
           temp_l1 = temp - sd)
```

It's possible at this point to go back to the wide format using `tidyr::spread`, but I would instead encourage you to leave your data in this format. Or it may even be expedient to go into yet a longer format where rather than encoding the +/- SD information in column names you have a SD multiplier column that takes values of `-1, 0, 1` and a single temp column. The format I have above will work well for, e.g., plotting confidence bands. The even longer format would generalize better if you were interested in say, +/- 2, 1.5, 1, .5 standard deviations and were running code on each individual estimate.

Comment: Thank you very much. I actually have read that paper, though sometimes it's still not second nature (particularly as a lot of my data come from excel pivots, which are often saved in a "spread" format because it's easier to look at them that way). ANYHOW this totally hit the nail on the head and is exactly what I was looking for, a clean, elegant solution. Thank you again.